# How to Avoid Pylint Error For Not Passing Argument to Celery Bound Method?

Tags: python-3.x, celery, pylint, celery-task

The project is meant to serve a machine learning model via a REST API. Here is the celery task declaration, along with a unit test to check the function is running on a sample input.

```
@celery.task(bind=True)
def run_prediction(self, inpath: str) -> pandas.DataFrame:
    '''
    :param inpath File location of the input feature
    '''
    # Do a lot of stuffs
    return output # type:pandas.DataFrame

if __name__=='__main__':
    # Do a unit test with a sample inpath
    pred:pandas.DataFrame=run_prediction(inpath=sample_inpath)
```

The `run_prediction` function can be triggered as a stand-alone normal function without caring about celery, and also as an asynchronous method with the `apply_async` provided by celery. (I did not expect it to have the functionality of a standalone function, so any explanation on that would be great.)

But the main issue is when I check the code via pylint (version 2.5.3), it throws an error and a warning, both saying the same thing.

```
model_utility.py:92:34: W0613: Unused argument 'self' (unused-argument)
model_utility.py:188:4: E1120: No value for argument 'self' in function call (no-value-for-parameter)
```

Does it mean somehow pylint is not aware of how to call the function? Can I update the code to have a 10/10 from pylint? Or should I change something about pylint itself?

For your information, using pylint as a package from my editor (Atom), if that is important to the discussion.

Comment: I don't understand where do your errors refer to? which lines in your example exactly?

Comment: If the code runs as expected and you just want to ignore these errors you can always disable these specific messages. You can do so py having this line in the beginning of your file:
`#pylint: disable=<error_number/name>,...`
in your example it would be:
`#pylint: disable=unused-argument,no-value-for-parameter`